# Creating a Object.New with a foreign key results in nil?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have two models:

```
class Todo < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :assigned_to, :class_name => "TeamMembership"
end
```

and

```
class TeamMembership < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :assigned_todos, :class_name => 'Todo', :foreign_key => :assigned_to, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

when I do:

```
Todo.new(:title=>'hello',:assigned_to=>TeamMembership.first)
```

(where `TeamMembership.first` is a valid record from the database), I get a `Todo` with

```
:title = hello
:assigned_to = nil
```

Why is `:assigned_to` nil, and how can I fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The "Rails way" to do this would be:

```
class Todo < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :team_membership
end

class TeamMembership < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :todos, depdendent: :destroy
end
```

And a `t.references :team_membership` line in the `create_table` block for your migration that creates the `todos` table.

Then to create a new `Todo` with the title "hello" that belongs to the first `TeamMembership`, you'd do:

```
TeamMembership.first.todos.build(title: "hello")
```

See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-many-association-reference

There may be some specific reason that you want to rename the association & foreign key, but you can still use the `build` method on the collection of todos.

Comment: If you haven't done this, is it worth fixing it afterwards? It means migrating a live app, not so sure of the benefit if it 'works'

Answer (score 0):

have you added any validation? if yes then try on console Todo.new(:title=>'hello',:assigned_to=>TeamMembership.first,:validate=>'false')
and see the result other wise please tell me the atributes of Todo

Comment: Hello, there is validation but it doesn't make any difference. Notice this is on 'New' not save so I don't think validation applies.

Comment: Please add here TeamMembership.first and Todo.first.sttributes

Comment: #<TeamMembership id: 305, created_at: "2014-02-04 19:50:24", updated_at: "2014-02-04 19:50:24", team_id: 34, user_id: 1, roles: "site_admin">

Comment: Todo.first.attributes
  Todo Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "todos".* FROM "todos" LIMIT 1
 => {"id"=>1, "title"=>"test 1", "created_at"=>Thu, 26 Dec 2013 19:46:19 UTC +00:00, "updated_at"=>Tue, 04 Feb 2014 19:50:24 UTC +00:00, "user_id"=>1, "assignee_id"=>2, "complete"=>true, "position"=>0, "id_md5"=>nil, "team_id"=>34, "creator"=>nil, "assigned_to"=>nil}

Comment: hye plz try to add Todo's atributes
try Todo.new(:title=>'hello',:assigned_to=>TeamMembership.first.id)...not sure

Comment: Got a type mismatch- expecting TeamMembership got integer

Answer (score 0):

OK, so it turns out the problem was:

- The database fields need to be renamed with _id as a suffix, creator_id etc.
- Then you need to put the ID in as an integer, rather than pass in the object.